# iOS Twitter Entities on search API

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter

I'm integrating some Twitter functions on my app. So basically what i want to do is to retrieve tweets based on some keywords (#hashtags) and from those extract if present pictures and present them to the user.

The problem is that on "GET Search" query such as `"http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=Twitter%20API&result_type=mixed&count=5"` entities are not supported so I'm wondering how can I achieve my task.

I thought to get all the tweets with that query and then for each tweet do this call "GET statuses/show/:id" so i can get the entities for each tweet- get the link in the tweet text - and then make another call to a service where tweet pictures are stored and shared but it seems inefficient, it needs a lot of connection.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At that time Twitter Search API didn't support entities, now it works properly

Answer (score 1):

Just % escape the #. In a URL %23 is a #.

This query will look for tweets tagged #iphone.

http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23iphone&result_type=mixed&count=5

To escape the string do this

NSString url = @"url with #hashtag";
NSString *escapedString = [url stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

That will replace the # with %23.

Comment: Well thanks for the suggestion...I'll fix it...but my problem is another one :)